# Best method to try and decipher this cipher text?

Tags: python, encryption, caesar-cipher

This is an example of a portion of the cipher text I need to decipher:

```
gsv wzlf zaw nbagsf zev gezivoovef bu vgveargl, qhfg orpv gsv lvzef gszg
xbnv zaw tb.  ube gsbfv jsb czff gsvre orivf zuobzg ba ybzgf, be uzxv bow
ztv ovzwrat sbefvf grtsg yl gsv yerwov, gsvre qbheavlrat rf oruv, gsvre
qbheavlrat rf sbnv.  zaw nzal zev gsv nva bu bow jsb nvg gsvre vaw
hcba gsv ebzw.
```

Anyone have any methods to try and decipher this? I have already used code to find out the most frequent letters that are within the text. I was thinking of a Vignere cipher, but I would like to know and hear any other approaches to this.

Comment: The first 'word' is "gsv". Looking through the cyphertext, the letter pair "gs" is common. Try "gs" → "th", which makes "v" → "e". From that find other letters.

Answer (score 2):

The letters are still formatted as if they were words, the punctuation gives it away. So pretty much each letter seems to just be substituted for another.
This is a mono-alphabetic cipher

Using the most frequent letters you worked out, you can try match it against the average usage of each word of the alphabet on average and match them directly. E.g. Wikipedia [letter frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency).

It should give most of it away.
Or you could brute force it with online software:
[DCode](https://www.dcode.fr/monoalphabetic-substitution) is a great website for this